# 'static' method modifier not working with Android widgets

Tags: java, android, non-static

In my Android Application, I want to change this method to static, however when I add 'static' to the method signature, my IDE tells me that a non-static context cannot be referenced from a static context (on the `findViewByID(R.id.listView)`.

```
public void populateListView(ArrayList<Income> incomeArray) {
    ArrayList<Income> array = incomeArray;
    ArrayAdapter<Income> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How could I make this method static?

Comment: static methods can be only invoked by static methods.

Comment: @N5.: That's not true at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

Comment: `findViewByID` is an instance method - so it needs to be invoked on an instance of the relevant class.

Comment: Those are not static. Look @ http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java

Answer (score 0):

make them global and Initialize your values out of your function or passing them as an argument, you are using `this.findViewById(R.id.listView)` which is not a static function.